# What happens to the $\color{red}s$ in Möbius' Inversion Formula?

Tags: arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

At the end of the Wiki page on [Möbius' Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations), the following relation is given:

$$
   g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{f(mx)}{m^\color{red}s}\quad\mbox{ for all } x\ge 1\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mu(m)\frac{g(mx)}{m^\color{red}s}\quad\mbox{ for all } x\ge 1. $$

It seems like the value of $\color{red}s$ doesn't matter for the value of $g(x)$. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: If you _define_ $g$ by $$g(x) = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{f(mx)}{m^s},$$ the value of $s$ does in general matter. Except for special $f$, different $s$ give rise to different $g$.

Comment: @DanielFischer then writing it $g_s(x)$ would be more appropriate, but assumed not to be necessary...

Comment: One can also look at it from the point of view "given two functions $f,g$, and a real or complex $s$, the one relation holds if and only if the other holds". Generally, for given $f,g$ there is at most one $s$ such that either relation holds.